# How to search and extract values from a Hashmap Stored in Arraylist

Tags: java, android, search, arraylist, hashmap

```
List<Map<String, String>> personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ();
String tempcnic = SBox.getText().toString();
HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < personlistcopy.size(); i++) {
    temp = personlistcopy.get(i);
    if (temp.get(TAG_CNIC) == tempcnic) {
        Toast.makeText(History.this, temp.get(TAG_CNIC), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        personList2.add(temp);
    }
    temp = null;
}
```

I have an `ArrayList` containing `HashMap`s,
`HashMap` contains 4 keys with corresponding values.

1. name
2. Cnic
3. Date
4. Time

**Kindly help me in doing "Search and find all `HashMap`s in `ArrayList` with given cnic and add them to a new `ArrayList`. The new `ArrayList` will have all records with that cnic."**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to do it with Java 8's `stream`:

```
List<Map<String, String>> personList = new ArrayList<>(); //Your list

List<Map<String,String>> filtered = personList.stream()
    .filter(p -> "your_cnic".equals(p.get("cnic")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want case insensitive comparison, you can use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`.

Here is non-stream solution (for Java 5, 6 and 7):

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); //Your list
List<HashMap<String,String>> filtered = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

for(HashMap<String, String> person : personList){
    if("your_cnic".equals(person.get("cnic"))){
        filtered.add(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes if you are using java 8.

Comment: @RANAARSLAN added another solution for Java 6 and 7.

Comment: add
(java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>)
in ArrayList cannot be applied
to
(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>)

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me Darshan

Comment: Yes Sure, i got an error: 
add (java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>) in ArrayList cannot be applied to (java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>)

Comment: It is saying voted casted by user less than 15 rating will not be displayed